# TypeError: Class method is not a function, confused about binding this

Tags: javascript, socket.io, this, function-binding

I have this class Game.

```
    class Game {
      constructor(player) {
        this.player1 = player;
      }

      getHost() {
        // player has property nickname
        return `Host: ${this.player1.nickname}`;
      }
    }
```

I believe the issue I am having is that getHost() is becoming unbound from it's context, however I'm not sure how to fix it. I'm learning JS and I'm pretty confused about this language's usage of `this`. I'm also using socket.io for the first time, so this adds a lot to the confusion for me.
My server script (the server works, just showing relevant parts):

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    // passed defined player
    socket.on('host game', (player) => { 
        const game = new Game(player);
        console.log(game.getHost()); // still works here
        io.sockets.emit("game created", game);
    });

});
```

Client:

```
socket.on("game created", (game) => {
    const gameElement = document.createElement("li");
    gameElement.innerHTML = game.getHost(); // ERROR
    games.appendChild(gameElement);
});
```

On the above marked line, I get the `Uncaught TypeError: game.getHost is not a function`.

Sorry if the socket.io functions make it more confusing, basically just when the game is passed from server to client, it doesn't work anymore.
Thanks for the help

Comment: if you log the game inside "game created" callback,what is the output you are getting?

Comment: Do you create an instance of game on the client?

Comment: You can not send functions from the server to the client. The class instances are JSON encoded which removes the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that socketio is serializing the object for you. Since a websocket is still just HTTP, you can't send an actual JS object over it. socketio handles serializing your object to JSON using `JSON.stringify(game)` behind the scenes. It will also convert that JSON string back into an object for you on the client side too.

Unfortunately when you do this you lose methods. For example:

```
let game = new Game({nickname: 'Bob Vance'});
game = JSON.stringify(game);
console.log(game) // will output {"player1":{"nickname":"Bob Vance"}}
```

You should see `{"player1":{"nickname":"Bob Vance"}}` in the console because serializing to JSON drops the methods but preserves properties. This is just normal JavaScript behaviour.

So what you have to do to get the methods back is create a new instance of a game on the client-side, and then use `Object.assign()` to build the object back up.

Example

```
let serializedGame= JSON.parse(game);
let newGameInstance = new Game({nickname: game.nickname});
Object.assign(newGameInstance, serializedGame);
```

Now you should be ok to call `newGameInstance.getHost()`

Comment: Thank you! I wouldn't have figured this out on my own. This made me realize I should rethink the structure of my server and client. I appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem  Glad I could help!